# Make a datetime variable static

Tags: bash, shell, loops, datetime, static

I have a script which calls another script in a loop.
Below is a sample/draft script.

test3.sh

```
for i in "${array[@]}";do
sh test4.sh
done
```

In test4.sh script something like below is happening:

```
  LogFileDateFormat=%Y%m%d_%H%M%S
    GetDateTime=`date +$LogFileDateFormat`
    LogDirectory="/cred/logs"
    LOG_FILE=$LogDirectory/test4_$GetDateTime.log
.
.Do Something >> $LOG_FILE
.
```

Now every time the loop is called from test3.sh , a new log is getting created because the log name is appended by date and time.
I want to write logs to just a single file.

I thought of some counter mechanism but again I am not able to restrict the LOG_FILE to just one name.

Comment: Pass the date/filename from test3 (outside of the loop) as an argument to test4.

Comment: Thanks @Socowi ..I was thinking of some many things..but this didn't strike me. :)

Comment: Maybe try to declare a variable with the path to the log file before the array and pass it to the script as an argument

Comment: @Amit : New file is getting created every time because you have given timestamp to your variable : `%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the logging inside test3.sh:

```
logfile=...... 
for  i in "${array[@]}";do
  sh test4.sh >>$logfile
done
```